# dependency error on npm package versions but they are installed

Tags: angular, npm, dependency-management

by sending the command:

```
npm list -g
```

I got this errors for example:

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.5.3, required by @angular/core@10.0.7
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.0.0, required by @angular/http@7.2.16
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.0.0, required by angular-in-memory-web-api@0.11.0
```

and more...but sending:

```
ng --version
```

I got this versione of rxjs:

```
rxjs 6.5.5
```

therefore the version of rxjs installed is higher than the required ones described in the errors. What's up? Why this inconsistency?

Comment: Have you tried to remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and try to install packages again?

Comment: no...I didn't...you mean the global node_modules?

Comment: nope, inside your project.

Comment: but "nmp list -g" is not related to any project ...